# Populate a form using Flask / Jinja2 template. Input text fields are truncating data

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to send data to Flask Jinja2 template and repopulate a text input inside of a form. When I do this my data gets truncated. For example:

App.py

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():    
    text = 'My long test entry'
    return render_template('test.html', text=text)
```

Template

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>  
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    test:<br>
    <input type="text" name="test" value={{text}}>    
  </form> 
</body>
```

Result

[image]

I want to populate with the entire string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need quotes around `{{text}}`

Here's what renders:

```
<input type="text" name="test" value=My long test entry>
```

Here's what you want to render:

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="My long test entry">
```

Here's what your code should look like:

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="{{text}}">
```